# How to delete multiple flash addresses in C?

Tags: c, stm32, keil, flash-memory

I try to erase flash address in stm32l011k4. My code like that;

```
#define SLAVE_ID_ADDR_I                             0x08080001
#define SLAVE_ID_ADDR_II                            0x08080002
#define SLAVE_ID_ADDR_III                           0x08080003
#define MASTERID                                    0x08080000

void software_erase(void){  

        HAL_FLASH_Unlock();

    /* Fill EraseInit structure*/
    EraseInitStruct.TypeErase   = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
    EraseInitStruct.PageAddress = SlaveID_III;              
    EraseInitStruct.NbPages     = 4;                                    

    if (HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct, &PAGEError) != HAL_OK)
    {
        playTone=3;
    }
    else{           
        MasterID = 0;
        SlaveID_I = 0;
        SlaveID_II = 0;
        SlaveID_III = 0;
        MasterID_loaded = 0;
        SlaveID_loaded_I = 0;
        SlaveID_loaded_II = 0;
        SlaveID_loaded_III = 0;
        clear_keyfobs = 1;
        playTone=2;
    }
}
```

Edit:
But I want to erase bytes between 0x08080001 - 0x08080003. Not all sections.
It's means "0x08080001, 0x08080002, 0x08080003" must be deleted but "0x08080000" must be remain.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The values given are not pages, but byte-addresses. You cannot delete single bytes in Flash.

Comment: Please read the documentation of your chip. It should tell you the smallest possible erase size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addresses are pointing to **EEPROM**, not flash.

[image]

You don't have to erase anything in EEPROM, just unlock it and write the new values.

However, in order to write a byte, you'd need a properly dereferenced pointer, an integer constant won't work.

```
#define SLAVE_ID_ADDR_I   (*(volatile unsigned char *)0x08080001)
#define SLAVE_ID_ADDR_II  (*(volatile unsigned char *)0x08080002)
#define SLAVE_ID_ADDR_III (*(volatile unsigned char *)0x08080003)
#define MASTERID          (*(volatile unsigned char *)0x08080000)

void software_erase(void)
{
    if(FLASH->PECR & FLASH_PECR_PELOCK)
        HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    SLAVE_ID_ADDR_I = 0;
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to say "page" when you mean "byte", and that doesn't make a lot of sense.

The smallest erasable unit of the STM32's flash is often called a "sector", and is much larger than a single byte.

It's possible to *program* (i.e. write, i.e. turn 1s into 0s) single words, but you cannot erase (i.e. turn 0s into 1s) less than a certain limit at a time. Usually the sector size is multiple kilobytes, and can also vary over the address space.